# Nonnegative integer combinations of binomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

A classical result of Polya and Ostrowski states that integral linear combinations of binomial coefficients ${x\choose k}$ is exactly the set of all polynomials $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f(\mathbb{Z})\subset\mathbb{Z}$.

**Question 1.**  If we allow only nonnegative integer coefficients, what will be the set of polynomials we get?

**Question 2.** Which polynomials are the nonnegative integer combinations of ${x\choose 0},{x+1\choose 1},{x+2\choose 2},\ldots,{x+k\choose k}$?